# Displaying content as html preview on merged cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to display content as html preview on the merged cell.

Sample:  **Test**

I merged cells from B2:C9

I want the range [B2:C9] to display  **Test** .

I tried;

```
Dim Ie As Object
Set Ie = CreateObject ("InternetExplorer.Application")
With Ie
    .Visible = False
    .Navigate "about: blank"
    .Document.Body.innerHTML = Sheets (Constant.Output_Sheet_Name) .Range ("B2"). Value
    .ExecWB 17, 0
    'Select all contents in browser
    .ExecWB 12, 2
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination: = Sheets (Constant.Output_Sheet_Name) .Range ("B2")
    .Quit
End With
```

It works on unmerged cells. I want it to work on merged cells.

Answer (score 0):

Working with merged cells is often problematic.

If you want to use the merged cells, I suggest you first unmerge the range B2:C9, then paste the html into the unmerged cell B2, and then merge range B2:C9 again.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Thanks @teylyn,

Because I only want the content displayed in the range [B2: C9].

If I don't merge cells, the content when I set can be very long beyond range [B2: C9]. Sample : [B2:M20].

It is out of the visible area I need.

If you have other solution, please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use Paste, then. Instead, use `range("B2").value = yourcopiedstuff`, then the pasted text will remain inside the one cell.

Comment: it will display: <b> Test </b> in cell. Not as HTML Preview.

Comment: Excel cells cannot interpret HTML. Excel does not use HTML for formatting